# Long load time in Visual Studio for Large Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

Is there a way to turn off intellisense in Visual Studio 2008?  I know about deleting a DLL to turn off intellisense in C++, but that doesn't work for C#.  I also know about the preferences but that just turns off the visual display.  I want to turn off ALL of intellisense so it does not scan my code at all.

Update 10/14/09: Eric was kind enough to take a look so I sent him some log info.  I'll post the resolution here when we get one.

Update: updated title to reflect the changed direction of the thread

#### Related Question

> [Turning off Intellisense for a single project in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552018/turn-off-intellisense-in-vs-2008-for-a-single-project)

Comment: Why?  It provides useful information. If you don't want intellisense, you can always program in notepad and copy/paste into Visual Studio. :-)

Comment: Or something like vim, emacs, notepad2, notepad++ if you want highlighting and indenting, etc.

Comment: I have a project that intellisense scans for 20+ minutes when loading.  See the other thread here about turning Intellisense off for just a single project.

Comment: I don't think you will notice a big speed difference. Note that the scanning (background compilation) is also required for Error detection and refactoring.

Comment: Brad, please link to that thread (Edit your Question) if it is relevant.

Comment: Henk: He means this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552018/turn-off-intellisense-in-vs-2008-for-a-single-project

Comment: What's the largest number of classes you guys have had in a single project?  This one (my data model) is over 1000, where 500 of them are parent classes and the other 500 are children of those parents.  THis performance problem is taking about 25% of each day waiting for the thing to load.

Comment: I suspect that either you are misdiagnosing the problem, or that you have hit some very strange bug in the analyzer. There's no way that we should be blocking for minutes. Can you email me and tell me more about your scenario and why you're diagnosing it as an intellisense problem? You can email me off my blog page, blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert. Thanks!

Comment: How long does a normal (re)build take?

Comment: Wow. When you get Eric Lippert's attention, you know Stack Overflow is working.

Comment: That's kind of you to say, but I'm just this guy, you know?

Comment: Wow, i attracted the big guns!  :)  Thanks for the help Eric - i'll pursue it via your blog, and even send the prj if you like.  I'll psot any resolution here for others.

Comment: No guarantees that I can help -- I actually know very little about the intellisense backend; I work on the compiler proper. But I can certainly get the attention of the IDE experts down the hall.

Comment: @Henk - once I wait the required 20 minutes, a build takes a slightly slow, but reasonable 5-6 minutes.  The solution is large (90 projects).  If I open JUST the offending project, load takes about 12-15 minutes.  If I load the entire solution with the offending project, 20+.  If i hack the solution file and remove the reference to the offending project, i can load the solution in about 2 minutes.

Comment: We've had projects larger than those class sizes and they load in a (small) fraction of the time. So something is fishy here. Maybe not neccessarily intellisense. Did you try to physically move the files. Maybe they somehow became extremely fragmented or something like this.

Comment: Who's taking odds that the source is on a network share?

Comment: @everyone - I hope you are all right that it's not intellisense, but i occasionally get that message saying "Visual STudio is working on a background thread" or something like that, and it starts listing each CS file as it gets processed.  I believe that's an Intellisense message.

Comment: BTW, i've emailed Eric with details so when I get an answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: OH, one more thing i just thought of - this prj was recently upgraded from VSTS2005 to VSTS2008.  VSTS2005 did not have these problems.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: It looks like you've become something of a celebrity in the programming (well, C# at least) world.

Comment: I'm sending again to your email now.

Comment: Try disabling source control integration and see if that resolves anything.  Probably not, but once we used to have terrible issues with large projects opening the first time, because of the pending checkins check over a very slow connection, and it would take nearly a half-hour to complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The guys on the VS team looked at this for me and found a problem with intellisense.  Here's their description:

"It looks like both of the files you gave me contain a part of static partial class EntityPropertyDescriptors, and I would guess that all the rest of the 500 files do too.  What’s happening is that as we build up our IntelliSense cache, each time we parse *one* of these files, we see that it has a static class in it, and we decide to see if that static class has any extension methods.  In order to look for the extension methods, we look through each method in *each* part to see if it’s an extension method.  This causes us to reparse *every file* in order to see if the type has any extension methods."

They found a similar problem with VS2010 but are fixing it now.  Unfortunately, they are not going to fix it in VS2008, so we are left with the workaround of putting all the partial classes into a single file.  They can still be partials, but they must be in the same physical file to get around the problem.

After combining all partial classes into a single file, load time for this problem project when from 30 minutes to about 10 seconds.

Big thanks to Eric Lippert and Kevin Pilch-Bisson for helping me with this.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks again for bringing it to our attention. I'm glad we could get this fixed for VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch off background compilation.

Here is a HowTo:

http://ira.me.uk/2008/09/01/switch-offon-visual-studio-2008-background-compilation/

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Show live semantic errors

You will still get error underlining, but you must hit the Build button before they show up.

Answer (score 1):

In tools > options > Text Editor > C# there is a Intellisense section which looks like it does what you want.

Comment: Sorry hadn't noted your comment about knowing about the preferences.

Comment: That's the preference that I've already tried.  It only turns off the display, not the scanning.  Note here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1(VS.71).aspx that it says the intellisense is available via keystroke even when it's turned off, thus it must be still scanning the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning your solution from all temporary files created by Visual Studio? Sometimes these files could get corrupted, the chances might especially be high if you migrated from VS 2005.

Close your solution, look for all *.suo and *.ncb files and remove/rename them, and then re-open the solution.

Just another thing to make sure: Are there any third-party add-ins installed? Try to start VS in SafeMode using the `/SafeMode` command-line option.

Comment: Good idea on the safemode.  It's still taking as long to load, but mem is much lower.  Interesting....

Comment: My mistake on the mem comment above - i ran the original test on my dekstop with 8gb, and the /safemode test on my laptop with 2gb.