# VS2008 intellisense performance issue with large number of partial static classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

My question is a follow-up to the issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556346/long-load-time-in-visual-studio-for-large-project/1652043#1652043)
regarding the Intellisense performance issue when building a large solution in VS2008 that has many *partial static* classes.

Since Microsoft does not seem to be addressing the issue for VS2008, I would like to know if there are other ways around the problem? Waiting for VS2010 is not an option at this time. The proposed solution in the previous post is not practical as some of the partial classes may be regenerated and this would be a maintenance headache.

Comment: Did you submitted this issue on Microsoft?

Comment: @Victor Hurdugaci: You may want to read that other post.

Answer (score 4):

The other post suggested the static class has at least some 500 members. This is highly indicative of a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). Correct this problem, and the original cause of the IntelliSense problems goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this kind of Problem with the RTM Build of VS2008 and compiling a large Webserver (AKA Ebay Webservice).

This Problem was fixed an an early Hotfix after RTM and its includes in the SP1 for Visual Studio 2008.